# Using CSS modules with Webpack and Typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, css-modules

I am trying to integrate CSS modules in to my project which uses Typescript and Next JS. Here's my setup so far:

```
   module.exports = withCustomBabelConfigFile(
      withTypeScript(withCSS({ 
      cssModules: true,
        babelConfigFile: path.resolve("./babel.config.js"),
        webpack(config, options) {
          config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'pages/index.tsx'),
            use: [
              'style-loader',
              {
                loader: 'typings-for-css-modules-loader',
                options: {
                  modules: true,
                  namedExport: true,
                  camelCase: true
                }

              }
            ],
          })
          return config
        }
      }))
    );
```

I'm trying to use the `typings-for-css-modules-loader` plugin to have Webpack auto-generate my TS typings for my CSS.

If I remove the `withCSS()` function from my config, the typings are generated but the CSS modules don't work as no CSS is added to the elements. However I keep the `withCSS()` in the config, the typings don't generate but the CSS modules work.

Has anyone used Next JS config in this situation before or know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!